# Bibliography issues in LyX

Tags: lyx

When I enter my sources, LyX doesn't break the lines. I clicked "Bibliography" in the menu, I entered [ 1 ] in the Key and my source in the Label to get the pdf I've pasted below. How do I get my source to not go off the screen? (I intentionally erased the author's name).

[image]

Comment: It will be easier for others to help you if you provide minimal examples, both a .tex and a [LyX minimal example](http://wiki.lyx.org/FAQ/MinimalExample).

Comment: I think you choose the style "Bibliography" *from the toolbar* (instead of *in the menu*). If so, you might update your question...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most of the styles which can be chosen from the drop down box on the toolbar in LyX apply to one entire or several paragraphs. The same is true for the "Bibliography" style.

The **reference text** itself is written as a paragraph. For the gray box, the **"Key" field** gives a reference a unique name throughout the document (if a ".bib" file were used that were called the BibTeX key) and the **"Label" field** holds the text that is displayed in the PDF when a reference occurs (e.g., by using "Insert > Citation" in LyX). BTW, the "Label" is optional and can be left empty. Then the references are enumerated instead.

The described parts in LyX produce to the following LaTeX code:

```
\bibitem[Label text]{Key}the reference text
```

Here is how a LyX document looks like

[image]

That produces the following LaTeX code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
... for a reference, see \cite{Falconer1990}.
\begin{thebibliography}{Fa}
\bibitem[Fa]{Falconer1990}K. Falconer, Fractal Geometry. Mathematical
Foundations and Applications, John Wiley \& Sons Ltd., Chichester,
1990.\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```